# Login with PayPal via link instead of integrated popout window

Tags: php, paypal

Currently on my application I'm doing integration with PayPal, however I can't seem to find a solution for performing OAuth via external link instead of doing it all within a popout window?

I've got this on my site:

```
<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/connect/api.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    paypal.use(['login'], function (login) {
        login.render ({
            "appid": "",
            "scopes":"openid profile email address profile https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
            "containerid":"cwppButton",
            "locale":"en-us",
            "text": "Connect with PayPal",
            "returnurl": "http://example.com/paypal/callback"
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I'd like the ability to redirect the customer directly to the login page myself (my backend is PHP) but I can't seem to find anything inside the PayPal API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `"fullPage":"true",`

You can generate such a button here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/reference/button-js-builder/

Or read [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#generate-a-paypal-button)

---

However, the popout window is a much better experience that keeps your site loaded in the background.

Redirecting away is an old integration method, and makes no sense for a modern website.